# viewController stays null while I try to set it as the dataSource for a view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, model-view-controller, delegates

I am trying to build a calculator with a graphing function, and I am using MVC designs.

So there are basically 2 MVC's

- `CalculatorViewController` and its view and model
- `GraphViewController` and its view and model

I am using `NavigationController` and setting the `rootView` to the view of the Calculator part, and if I input the formula in this view, and press a `Graph` button, a segue will take the program to the graphing part of the view.

But the graphing view needs to know what points to plot, and that is taken care of by setting the `GraphViewController` as a property `dataSource` for the `GraphView`, such that the `GraphView` can call a method defined in the protocol of the `dataSource` and get an array of points to draw.

So currently the problem is, when I try to call that protocol method to get the array of points, it turns out that my `dataSource` in the view is always `null`.

This puzzles me quite a bit since I don't quite understand how the controller of the view itself could be `null` while the view is still displaying and alive on the screen.

The code I am using to setup the `dataSource` in the graph controller is the following:

```
  // code in GraphViewController.m
  @synthesize graphView = _graphView;

  - (void)setGraphView:(GraphView *)graphView {
      _graphView = graphView;
      self.graphView.dataSource = self;
  }
```

The view also synthesized its property `dataSource` as following:

```
  // code in GraphView.m
  @synthesize dataSource = _dataSource;
```

Comment: How does setGraphView: get called? Show the code where you set that.

Comment: @rdelmar shouldn't that get called automatically when the `segue` moves from the `CalculatorView` to `GraphView`? I actually didn't call that method. This might be what's causing the problem. Where should I call that then? If the changing the view does not call the method automatically

Comment: Might? Put a log in there and know for sure.

Comment: @rdelmar hmm it's actually not getting called. Should I call it in prepareForSegue?

Comment: I don't know. What exactly is graph view? Is it GraphViewController's self.view? A subview?

Comment: @rdelmar it's GraphViewController's `self.graphView` since I named it as a property called 'graphView' of the controller.

Comment: Then in GraphViewController's viewDidLoad, have self.graphView.dataSource = self;

Comment: @rdelmar I did that and it looks like the dataSource is still null.

Comment: @rdelmar I can't really do it in prepareForSegue either since my `graphView` is a private property.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30031/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-enzo)